# Populating table view with thousands of searchable objects

Tags: arrays, swift

I am looking to populate a table view with thousands of searchable objects. I looked at the UISearchController Tutorial at: https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started. Looks like the searchable objects were put in the viewDidLoad method, but what if I have thousands of them? That could put thousands of lines on the viewDidLoad method. I tweaked the source code and noticed I could put the candies array in a separate file and declare it another name like candiesAndMore and change the code below as candies = candiesAndMore. Is there another way I could approach this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

...

candies = [
  Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Bar"),
  Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Chip"),
  Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Dark Chocolate"),
  Candy(category:"Hard", name:"Lollipop"),
  Candy(category:"Hard", name:"Candy Cane"),
  Candy(category:"Hard", name:"Jaw Breaker"),
  Candy(category:"Other", name:"Caramel"),
  Candy(category:"Other", name:"Sour Chew"),
  Candy(category:"Other", name:"Gummi Bear"),
  Candy(category:"Other", name:"Candy Floss"),
  Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Coin"),
  Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Egg"),
  Candy(category:"Other", name:"Jelly Beans"),
  Candy(category:"Other", name:"Liquorice"),
  Candy(category:"Hard", name:"Toffee Apple")]

...

}
```

Comment: You need a database, not hardcoded data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using Core Data framework. 
Create an entity for Candies in Core Data, store the information there, fetch the candies in ViewDidLoad() and then use.